# Problem related to login and profile page

Tags: python, django

I am working on a python Django project. I have a little problem, When I make login through login form after registration. the main page was redirected to login page again despite configuring it to be redirected to profile page.

I tried many solutions and found no solutions

This is the Github repo link for the project:
https://github.com/Demo-23home/vacc/tree/main

What's the solution please?

Comment: please add a code snippet

Comment: https://github.com/Demo-23home/vacc/tree/main

Comment: this is the repo link for the project

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: add code in question not image

Answer (score 0):

*Add this 2 line in setting.py*

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: I tried but the problem is still existed